# How can I modify the constraints of this LP solver to check whether a recommended configuration is valid?

Tags: javascript, linear-programming

Given a theatre of 200 seats, find the best-recommended configuration of seating for each group that can fit all 200 seats given that a row only consists of 8 seats.

[LP Solver](https://npm.runkit.com/javascript-lp-solver/)

```js
var javascriptLpSolver = require("javascript-lp-solver")

var groups = [30, 43, 15, 20, 89, 3]
var sum = groups.reduce(function(a, b){
        return a + b;
    }, 0);
    
for(var i=0; i<groups.length; i++){
var solver = javascriptLpSolver,
  results,
  model = {
    "optimize": "cost",
    "opType": "min",
    "constraints": {
        "person": {"equal": groups[i]},
        "cost": {"max": 3*groups[i]},
        "total_seats": {"max": sum}
    },
    "variables": {
        "one-seater": {
            "person": 1,
            "cost": 3
        },
        "two-seater": {
            "person": 2,
            "cost": 2
        },
        "three-seater": {
            "person": 3,
            "cost": 1
        },
        "four-seater": {
            "person": 4,
            "cost": 1
        },
        "five-seater": {
            "person": 5,
            "cost": 1
        },
        "six-seater": {
            "person": 6,
            "cost": 1
        },
        "seven-seater": {
            "person": 7,
            "cost": 3
        },
        "eight-seater": {
            "person": 8,
            "cost": 1
        },
    },
    "ints": {"one-seater": 1, "two-seater": 1, "three-seater": 1, "four-seater": 1, "five-seater": 1, "six-seater": 1, "seven-seater": 1, "eight-seater": 1,}
};

results = solver.Solve(model);

console.log(results);
}
```

^ You can copy-paste the code into the LP Solver link above to run the code

Currently, it calculates the recommended configuration correctly per group based on a weightage scheme from 1-Seater to 8-Seater (where undesirable configurations like 1/7-Seaters 'costs' more compared to others) but it doesn't take into consideration if the recommended configuration fits into the leftover seats.

Here are the results given by the Solver:
[image: Results]

If I follow the recommended configurations fully, I would be left with 20 seats that are empty:
[image: Seating Final Result]

How can I tweak the constraint of the LP to check if a configuration is valid?